# Upgrade Windows XP 32bit to Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, upgrade

I've got a computer with windows xp 32bit installed on it and I want to upgrade/clean install it to Windows 7 64bit.

I've tried the following:

booting from the CD
booting from USB
Changing my bios to load the CD/USB first
Tried to format the hard drive wont let me do that.

None of the above have worked and I'm running out of ideas, is there anything else I can try to install a fresh version of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your processor is capable of running a 64 bit operating system? There is some information on how to check this [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows-frequently-asked-questions) under the heading:

> How do I tell if my computer can run a 64-bit version of Windows

There is a subsection there for XP.

Comment: @TomMaton If you confirm that your process is okay for a 64 bit OS then please can you describe in more detail what is happening when you try to boot from CD / USB.

Comment: Hi Chris, I've run the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor and its says that its compatible. WHen I try to boot from the CD/USB it comes up with press any key to boot from CD, I press keys and nothing, it just continues to the loading of XP.

Comment: @TomMaton Okay, so what happens when you try to boot from CD or USB?

Comment: WHen I try to boot from the CD/USB it comes up with press any key to boot from CD, I press keys and nothing, it just continues to the loading of XP

Comment: @TomMaton usually there is a specific key that you can press during boot up (before windows) to goes which drive to boot from. This varies by manufacturer, but is often the del key or F12. If no luck with these try the other function keys.

Comment: Yep, I've done this and specified the cd-rom to boot first but still no luck. :(

Comment: @TomMaton Have you tried inserting the disk while logged into XP and running the setup.exe program from your CD drive (it may auto start when you put the CD in)?

Comment: I've tried that, I get Setup.exe is not a valid win32 application. But from reading blogs I should be able to do this and do a custom installation but getting no where.

Comment: Sorry, I am all out of ideas then. I agree that you should be able to do this as a custom install booting from CD. It may be worth moving this question to Super User as you may get more response there (Stack Overflow is really intended for programming questions).